# What are the incrementing numbers that appear when CtrlP loads?

Tags: vim, plugins, macvim

I've noticed that CtrlP is consistently quite slow right after a file loads or when pulling up a new buffer. It happens each time I get the

```
<incrementing numbers> (press ctrl-c to abort)
```

message. Here's a [screenshot](http://cl.ly/461u2t350p0D1A0u0D22) of what CtrlP looks like when it's being slow. Once it loads the `prt path <mru>={ ... etc` part, it works lightning-quick.

I'm using a fairly unmodified version of MacVim with Janus. I'm just curious about what's going on there. I would assume that the numbers are the catalog of files CtrlP is indexing. Does it re-index at each window/buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the number of files indexed. The index is rebuilt every time you run `:CtrlP` in an "uncached" directory.

You shouldn't do `:CtrlP` in your home directory as it's sure to be very large: indexing it will take a lot of time and will, for the most part, be useless.

Read the documentation for how to set caching options: `:help ctrlp-options`.

```
let g:ctrlp_clear_cache_on_exit=0
```

is a good start.

Comment: Ah. You know, that makes sense about the home directory. However, with no existing windows open, hitting Cmd-N then Ctrl-P seemed the quickest way to bring up <random file>. I suppose a guy could just keep a buffer open, but that seems rather inelegant.

Comment: Where to start? Each time you do `Cmd-n` a new Vim instance is created with your `$HOME` as "workind directory" by default. Any command, including `:CtrlP`, you'll execute between that point and the next time the working directory is changed is going to assume that the root is `$HOME`. If you don't enable caching, CtrlP is going to index your whole `$HOME` each time. Also, the index will probably be huge and full of useless entries (think MP3s, PDFs, images, videos…), slowing down the fuzzy matching algorhythm and anhilating any hope of speed, reliability and accuracy.

Comment: There are more efficient ways to use MacVim: install the Open In MacVim droplet if you are a Finder.app guy or use the `mvim` script bundled with MacVim if you are a Terminal.app guy or use Quicksilver… or simply use `Cmd-o`. CtrlP and friends aren't really designed as universal file openers. If you really insist on using these tools that way you must learn their limitations and how to work around them. `:CtrlP ~/Work/projectname`, for example, summons CtrlP's interface with `~/Work/projectname` as "root" which will make your life considerably easier.

Comment: Hmm. Lots to think about there. Thanks for your insight.